# Typescript :: Lodash :: Arrays <-> Object for fast lookup

Tags: typescript, lodash

I have two classes `MyObject` and `MyObjectJSON`, along with helper methods for converting between the two: `myObj.toJSON()` and `MyObject.fromJSON()`.

Now, I have 2 constructs of the above classes that I need to convert between.

1. A map of `MyObject` instances with keys equal to `id`: `{ [id: number]: MyObject }`
2. A list of `MyObjectJSON` instances: `MyObjectJSON[]`

How can I convert between these two constructs? I'm using `lodash`.

Answer (score 0):

```
let mapA: { [id: number]: MyObject } = {};
mapA[obj1.id] = obj1;
mapA[obj2.id] = obj2;
mapA[obj3.id] = obj3;
// {
//   1: MyObject,
//   2: MyObject,
//   3: MyObject
// }

let mapB: { [id: number]: MyObjectJSON };
mapB = lodash.mapValues<MyObject, MyObjectJSON>(mapA, it => it.toJSON());
// {
//   1: MyObjectJSON,
//   2: MyObjectJSON,
//   3: MyObjectJSON
// }

let listB: MyObjectJSON[];
listB = lodash.map<MyObject, MyObjectJSON>(mapA, it => it.toJSON());
// [ MyObjectJSON, MyObjectJSON, MyObjectJSON ]
```